# Url rewriting - 2 rules with same shape

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've done some url rewriting for a project. But i have a problem.

In my project i have 3 differents level of categories. Its possible to go from category1 to category 3  and from category 1 to category 2 and next category 3.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   categorie3.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2   [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   categorie4.php?cat=$1&cat3=$2    [NC,QSA]
```

Before applying rewriting, i could know on which page to redirect the user with the code below

```
<h3 class="portfolio-title font-alt"><a href="categorie3.php?cat=<?= $cat ?>&cat2<?= $value["url"] ?>"><?= $value["titre"] ?></a></h3>
<h3 class="portfolio-title font-alt"><a href="categorie4.php?cat<?= $cat ?>cat3=<?= $_GET["cat3"] ?>"><?= $value["titre"] ?></a></h3>
```

but after after applying those rules i'm not able to know on which page to redirect and by default it redirect to the first link :

```
<h3 class="portfolio-title font-alt"><a href="<?= $cat ?>/<?= $value["url"] ?>"><?= $value["titre"] ?></a></h3>
<h3 class="portfolio-title font-alt"><a href="<?= $cat ?>/<?= $_GET["cat3"] ?>"><?= $value["titre"] ?></a></h3>
```

How can i specify on which page it should redirect? Thanks for your help i hope its well explained.

Comment: You can't have two different rules with the exact same regex. The rewrite module have no way of knowing which one you mean and will always go with the first match. You need to have different URL-patterns for different URL's. Either add a prefix or some param in the URL that differs.

Comment: Not possible. You have to specify something in your URL structure that indicates which .php file it should go to and which variables it should use.

Comment: Alright can you guys give me an example?

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/cat1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$`, `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/cat2/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$`, etc... then use the URL: `<?= $cat ?>/cat1/<?= $value["url"] ?>` and so on...

Comment: Okay thanks , but its no the result i'm expecting having cat1 or cat2 in the url is a problem for the seo and what my client wish

Comment: Change it to something else then. The point is, you need to have different URL patterns...